# Warning VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update Purecomponent

Tags: react-native, expo, flatlist

I am using expo managed work flow, Flatlist

Scenario: User selects a country-->the screen should display/highlight the selected row/country
Question:
Please suggest what should I do to avoid the warning

"VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. Object {
"contentLength": 10140,
"dt": 7873,
"prevDt": 1293,
}"

Countrycode.js

```
export const Countrylistdata= [
  {
    "country": "Afghanistan ",
    "callingCode": "+993",
    "flag":require("../img/af.png"),
  },
  {
    "country": "Åland Islands ",
    "callingCode": "+358"
  },
]
```

SignupPublic.js

```
import {Countrylistdata} from "./Countrycode";

export default class SignupPublic extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      countryList:Countrylistdata,
      countryCodeSelected:"",
      countryNameeSelected:"",
      itemindex:"",
      };
  }


<FlatList
style={{flex:1}}
data={this.state.countryList}
keyExtractor={(item,index)=>item.country.toString()}
initialNumToRender={15}
extraData={this.state.countryNameeSelected}

renderItem={  ({item, index})=> 

<TouchableOpacity  onPress={() =>this.selectedCountry(item.country, item.callingCode, index)} 
//style={color=this.state.countryNameeSelected==item.country?"yellow": "white"}
style={{backgroundColor:this.state.countryNameeSelected==item.country?"#B4FCEC":"white"}}
>
 
  <View  style={{ flexDirection:"row", justifyContent:"space-between",width:"80%",height:40,alignSelf:"center", marginTop:10}}>
  <Text style={{fontSize:18, flexWrap:"wrap",width:"78%"}}>
    {item.country} ({item.callingCode})
  </Text>
  <MaterialIcons name="done" size={28} color={this.state.countryNameeSelected ==item.country? "green":"white"} /> 
  
  </View>
   </TouchableOpacity>
}

/>
```

Answer (score -1):

to avoid such warnings you

```
react-native-largelist-v3
```

there are many issues with FlatList. I have done all the optimization, used pure components but nothing improved. the performance improved but it then stuck the UI. so the Best Solution is  `react-native-largelist-v3`. Here is s a [link](https://github.com/aftabaminzoobiapps/Optimizedsection_list/blob/main/App.js) for optimized FlatList. and this is the solution for https://github.com/aftabaminzoobiapps/largerlist

Comment: Thanks @Aftab. Will this work in Expo managed work flow?